# Error in if (is.na(col)) { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, plotly

My code had been working from long time but recently I have seen an error. I am posting the below code as an example only and the approach is exactly same. So I make 3D scatter plot to compare values of different months and I have one baseline value to compare with.

Each month I compare the results with the previous months so when the results = previous months, I get black point, if its less than previous month, I get red point otherwise its green.

Here's my code:

```
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
Jan22 <- c(1,4,2,3,4,5)
Feb22 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)


data <- data.frame(x, Jan22,Feb22)

cols1<- ifelse(data$Feb22 > data$Jan22, "green", ifelse(data$Feb22 < data$BJan22,"red", "black"))

size1 <- Feb22 - Jan22

plot_ly(data, x = data$x, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'scatter')%>%
  add_markers(y = data$Jan22,z= "Baseline", color = I("Black"), size = 1)%>%
  add_markers(y = data$Feb22,z= "Feb-22", color = I(cols1), size = size1)
```

I am trying to understand why the code has started giving this error now:

Error in if (is.na(col)) { : the condition has length > 1

The similar code had been working perfect previously.

Comment: Your code works fine for me using plotly version `‘4.10.1` on R 4.2.2. I only get a warning "`line.width` does not currently support multiple values.".

Comment: Ah it's the version issue then! Is it possible for you to share the version of plotly you are using?

Comment: See my comment: 4.10.1

Comment: I just updated plotly and it's working now. Thank you for the support!